# Colors in xcolor and color models

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I did an experiment on the different color models available in xcolor together with the predefined colors. I observe that the colors vary alot depending on the color model. WHY?

- Why does the colors vary so much depending on the color model for the
  predefined colors?
- How are the default values chosen? To they follow a specific color model?
- What color model should I choose?
- Why is Cyan in cmyk blue?
- Which color model is best for printing?

In the code example below the default colors are displayed in the second column.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \huge
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \selectcolormodel{default}
        \node at (0,0){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \input{colordata}
                \node at (7.5,1.5) {\textbf{default}};
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        };
        \selectcolormodel{cmyk}
        \node at (15,0.035){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \input{colordata}
                \node at (7.5,1.5) {\textbf{cmyk}};
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        };
        \selectcolormodel{cmy}
        \node at (30,-0.01){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \input{colordata}
                \node at (7.5,1.5) {\textbf{cmy}};
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        };
        \selectcolormodel{rgb}
        \node at (-15,0.035){
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \input{colordata}
                \node at (7.5,1.5) {\textbf{rgb}};
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

% first part of colordata.tex
 % \filldraw[color = red] (0,-0) rectangle (15,-0+1); \node at (7.5,-0+0.5) {red };
 % \filldraw[color = green] (0,-1) rectangle (15,-1+1); \node at (7.5,-1+0.5) {green };
 % \filldraw[color = blue] (0,-2) rectangle (15,-2+1); \node at (7.5,-2+0.5) {blue };
 % \filldraw[color = cyan] (0,-3) rectangle (15,-3+1); \node at (7.5,-3+0.5) {cyan };
 % \filldraw[color = magenta] (0,-4) rectangle (15,-4+1); \node at (7.5,-4+0.5) {magenta };
 % \filldraw[color = yellow] (0,-5) rectangle (15,-5+1); \node at (7.5,-5+0.5) {yellow };
 % \filldraw[color = black] (0,-6) rectangle (15,-6+1); \node at (7.5,-6+0.5) {black };
 % \filldraw[color = white] (0,-7) rectangle (15,-7+1); \node at (7.5,-7+0.5) {white };
 % \filldraw[color = gray] (0,-8) rectangle (15,-8+1); \node at (7.5,-8+0.5) {gray };
 % \filldraw[color = white] (0,-9) rectangle (15,-9+1); \node at (7.5,-9+0.5) {white };
 % \filldraw[color = darkgray] (0,-10) rectangle (15,-10+1); \node at (7.5,-10+0.5) {darkgray };
 % \filldraw[color = lightgray] (0,-11) rectangle (15,-11+1); \node at (7.5,-11+0.5) {lightgray };
 % \filldraw[color = brown] (0,-12) rectangle (15,-12+1); \node at (7.5,-12+0.5) {brown };
 % \filldraw[color = lime] (0,-13) rectangle (15,-13+1); \node at (7.5,-13+0.5) {lime };
 % \filldraw[color = olive] (0,-14) rectangle (15,-14+1); \node at (7.5,-14+0.5) {olive };
 % \filldraw[color = orange] (0,-15) rectangle (15,-15+1); \node at (7.5,-15+0.5) {orange };
 % \filldraw[color = pink] (0,-16) rectangle (15,-16+1); \node at (7.5,-16+0.5) {pink };
 % \filldraw[color = purple] (0,-17) rectangle (15,-17+1); \node at (7.5,-17+0.5) {purple };
 % \filldraw[color = teal] (0,-18) rectangle (15,-18+1); \node at (7.5,-18+0.5) {teal };
 % \filldraw[color = violet] (0,-19) rectangle (15,-19+1); \node at (7.5,-19+0.5) {violet };
 % \filldraw[color = Apricot] (0,-20) rectangle (15,-20+1); \node at (7.5,-20+0.5) {Apricot };
 % \filldraw[color = Aquamarine] (0,-21) rectangle (15,-21+1); \node at (7.5,-21+0.5) {Aquamarine };
```

Comment: It depends also your display drivers and rendering. Try the same PDF on your phone and it would be almost completely different. Your question needs a book rather than answer. It is quite involved. For example additive and subtractive models lead to different things. CMYK is mostly meant for printing.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know any good books?

Comment: It also depends on the printer... (in addition to all the other things mentioned by percusse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not intend to write a comprehensive analysis but give some hint to your subproblems.

> Why does the colors vary so much depending on the color model for the predefined colors?

We all agree that by `red` we mean the *reddest* color in the current space. (Intuitively there must be something representing that color, either named `red` or `reddest`.) But the fact is that, even the phrase *reddest* is well-defined, the reddest color varies from space to space. Some color spacess, for instance the Lab-family, do not contain the reddest but in which the red could be as red as you wish.

> How are the default values chosen? To they follow a specific color model?

Some color spaces are called **absolute** for their colors being unambiguous. For example when saying `#FF0000` in **AdobeRGB**, I am indicating *that* red , a color stimulating people's optic nerves in *that* way.

For an absolute color space, colors are chosen by the agency developing that space. For a non-absolute color space you need to associate it to an absolute one, since then the colors are determined.

> What color model should I choose?

Depends on what are you doing. Different models are developed for different purpose. The roughest list is

- For screens: RGB
- For printers: CMYK

> Why is Cyan in CMYK blue?

Well it is *blue* as an adjective but not `blue` in RGB. `cyan`(CMYK) is a color that *seems like* between `yellow`(RGB) and `blue`(RGB). And `cyan`(RGB) is defined as `#00FFFF`(RGB)

> Which color model is best for printing?

<del>CMYK</del>

<del>Pantone</del>

Nowadays computers/printers are smart enough to translate between color spaces. All you need to do is to choose a color from an space and declare the color-space pair.

The only problem is that your screen/printer may not be able to display/print the absolute color properly. This is a hardware issue and color models cannot help.