Color outputs differ when using `rgb` vs. `cmyk` target color model
Setup
Consider the following two files:
rgb.tex:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue!50] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

cmyk.tex:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue!50] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I compiled these two files to pdf files and then used the commands
magick convert -density 500 -alpha on "rgb.pdf" "rgb.png"
and
magick convert -density 500 -alpha on "cmyk.pdf" "cmyk.png"
I obtained the following images:
rgb.png:

cmyk.png:

The question
Why do the colors differ? I thought that color models were only about internals and not about visible effects.

related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598875/consistent-color-appearance-with-rbg-and-cmyk-color-models and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225331/colors-in-xcolor-and-color-models

I think my question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225331/271855 .
